Google Play Store ask to turn on internet connection for application
Google asked us to change the application to target SDKversion 34. It was 33 before. The test in Android Studio did not show any problems. I sent the new version to the playstore and almost everything works, except for the fact that if someone wants to run the application offline, the Play Store will give him a message that he is not connected to the Internet and will not start the application until he is connected.
I tried to uninstall from the application  everything that could be related to the Internet or downloads, I removed requests for advertisements, the system for protecting personal data - consent manager, but nothing helps. The application works offline only if it is started while the Internet is on and then the Internet is turned off while the application is running.
I tried restarting the mobile phone, deleting the play store data cache, deleting play store updates.
One of the things that I have now found out through testing is that the new Play Store system - Automatic integrity protection causes my application to malfunction in offline mode. Disabling it while publishing removed this problem for now. Information about this problem has been sent to Google.

Did you find any solutions for this bug?I faced to this issue and my users commented about this with low star.

At present I need to turn off Play store Automatic integrity protection and it works. Also offline. There was also one another bug in google open ads system, which did the same problem, but new version is OK.
